# Extract date from string with another numbers from R

Tags: date

I need to extract the date from this text:

```
Mellisoni 2014 Malbec (Columbia Valley (WA))
Okapi 2013 Estate Cabernet Sauvignon (Napa Valley)
Podere dal Nespoli 2015 Prugneto Sangiovese (Romagna)
Simonnet-Febvre 2015 Chablis
Lagler 2012 1000 Eimerberg Smaragd Neuburger (Wachau)
```

I use this code:

```
vino<-mutate(vino, year1=sub("^.*([0-9]{4}).*", "\\1", vino$title))
```

It works, but I have the last value extract on 1000 instead of 2012, how can I fix it if have another numbers?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: i used the software R